# How to remove root@localhost: from termux Command line?

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, terminal, terminal-emulator

```
root@localhost:~#
username@localhost:~$
```

There is something like this on the command line when you install Linux distros on Termux. How can it be removed?
or atleast reduced to:

```
#
$
```

How to remove root@localhost from termux Command line?

Comment: If you have further questions or clarifications, please [edit] your question to include them. Thank you!

Comment: You tagged this with both [tag:debian] and [tag:ubuntu], so I wonder which distribution you're using. Or if Termux itself is the relevant one. Also, the prompt is printed by the shell, so the answer depends on the shell you're using. That looks like Bash, but I could be wrong too.

Answer (score 2):

username green:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

root red:

```
 PS1='\[\033[01;31m\]\u:\[\033[01;00m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

Simple #  and $:

```
 PS1='$ '
```

If you wanted to change your shell prompts on a more permanent basis, you could modify your `.bashrc` by adding the following lines to the bottom of the file.